# How do you parallelize an anti-dependent loop in C using OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

I'm teaching myself OpenMP, and I'm trying to make a loop, where the instructions are anti-dependent, parallel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()

{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i;
    int n = 10;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i + 1] + a[2 * i];
        printf("%d, %d\n", a[i], i);
        }


}
```

When I do not use OpenMp, the result is `3 6 9 12 15`. I'm trying to reproduce that result with OpenMp, but I get different answers every time. Do I need to rewrite the loop?

Comment: Not everything can be parallelized. You need to modify your algorithm to be more `parallel`-friendly

Comment: @EugeneSh. How would I do that?

Comment: Yes, you certainly do need to rewrite the loop.  Spend some time with pencil and paper to see what happens when two (or more) threads work 'simultaneously' on `a`; it's not pretty.  An easy strategy for this kind of problem is to make `a_old` and `a_new` and to always execute updates such as `a_new[i] = a_old ...`.  At the end of each iteration do some index swapping, or figure out updating `old` from `new`.  This approach costs memory but buys parallelisability.